# How to filter based on duplicate values in one column and consecutive values in another using PLSQL?

Tags: plsql, count, duplicates

I have a database table that contains some duplicate rows in one particular column. I'd like to show only those rows but ONLY when an adjacent column has consecutive numbers for each set of matching duplicates. The picture below demonstrates:

[image: Filter for Duplicates]

Here's what I've come up with so far (the column names below are different from the picture above which was done to avoid conflict with defined SQL functions):

```
SELECT BIZ_DATE, AMT, COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE WHERE TRAN_DATE 
= '03-APR-2000' GROUP BY  AMT, BIZ_DATE, AMT HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This seems to work fairly well for getting dupes in the `amt` column.

Now, how do I get it to take into account only the consecutive values in the `trans_id` column?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: Erm...to quickly find duplicates that are causing issues without too much work. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe there are other ways to collect this kind of data.  I've posted a non-plsql approach below.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL isn't strictly required to find data sharing one attribute but having consecutive values on another attribute.

Using your general table structure, the following will locate any transaction pair sharing the same BIZ_DATE and AMT, with adjacent TRANS_IDs.

After creating and loading the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE    (
    BIZ_DATE DATE          NOT NULL,
    NAME     VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
    AMT      NUMBER        NOT NULL,
    TRANS_ID NUMBER        NOT NULL    );

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    (BIZ_DATE, NAME, TRANS_ID, AMT)
    VALUES (TO_DATE('17-MAY-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'BOB', 8086, 159);

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    (BIZ_DATE, NAME, TRANS_ID, AMT)
    VALUES (TO_DATE('17-MAY-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'BOB', 8085, 159);

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    (BIZ_DATE, NAME, TRANS_ID, AMT)
    VALUES (TO_DATE('17-MAY-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'BOB', 9088, 159);

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    (BIZ_DATE, NAME, TRANS_ID, AMT)
    VALUES (TO_DATE('17-MAY-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'BOB', 9087, 159);

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    (BIZ_DATE, NAME, TRANS_ID, AMT)
    VALUES (TO_DATE('17-MAY-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'BOB', 1111, 159);

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    (BIZ_DATE, NAME, TRANS_ID, AMT)
    VALUES (TO_DATE('17-APR-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),'BOB', 5903, 159);

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
    (BIZ_DATE,NAME, TRANS_ID, AMT)
    VALUES (TO_DATE('17-MAR-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),'BOB', 5904, 160);
```

One can compare adjacent values via analytic functions:

```
SELECT
  BIZ_DATE,
  AMT,
  TRANS_ID,
  PRIOR_TRANS_ID
FROM
  (SELECT
     BIZ_DATE,
     AMT,
     TRANS_ID,
     LAG(TRANS_ID, 1, TRANS_ID)
     OVER (PARTITION BY BIZ_DATE, AMT
       ORDER BY TRANS_ID ASC)
       AS PRIOR_TRANS_ID
   FROM MY_TABLE
   WHERE BIZ_DATE = TO_DATE('17-MAY-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))
WHERE (TRANS_ID - PRIOR_TRANS_ID) = 1;
```

Result:

```
BIZ_DATE   AMT TRANS_ID PRIOR_TRANS_ID
2015-05-17  159 8086    8085
2015-05-17  159 9088    9087
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending *how* you want to get back your "duplicate" rows, something *like* that might do the trick:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR c IS SELECT * FROM T ORDER BY AMT,NAME,TRANS_ID;
  curr_rec c%ROWTYPE;
  base_rec c%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR curr_rec IN c
  LOOP
    IF curr_rec.AMT = base_rec.AMT AND curr_rec.NAME = base_rec.NAME
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(base_rec.TRANS_ID);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' ');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(curr_rec.TRANS_ID);
    ELSE
        base_rec := curr_rec;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
NULL;
END;
```

This is a simple loop over the sorted rows to find pseudo-duplicate rows based on the criterion `curr_rec.AMT = base_rec.AMT AND curr_rec.NAME = base_rec.NAME` (or whatever else you need, as long as it matches a *prefix* of your cursor's `SORTED` clause)

Given your sample data, the output is:

```
8085 8086
8085 8087
8085 8088
```

Comment: Not sure I know how to use this. The script just said that it was finished. No output though. I actually don't need to see the Trans_id in the results. I just need the results to appear as the bottom image (desired result) but FILTERED by only those records that are consecutive in another column. Thus, the results should resemble the desired result table exactly. (is possible)